# Is preparing for Shabbat a Mitzvah?

Tags: shabbat

Is doing general housework (cleaning, dusting) unrelated to Shabbat, but in honor of Shabbat, a mitzvah?

What I mean is: there are certain things that we must do for shabbos like cook and get dressed, and others Chazal tell us to do like make our bed and set the table.

But, are other ordinary things like sweeping the floor and cleaning your desk for Shabbat a mitzvah?

Comment: See Shabbat 119a

Comment: It would help if you explained what you mean by mitzvah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gemara and Shulchan Aruch all give examples of doing something that is related to the food or clothing,  although the Rambam uses a word of "housework", it is still inconclusive if it includes things that would of been done anyway.

I did find in the Chut Hashani (R' Nissim Karelitz) Chelek 1, 4;1 that he says that if your going away or not using the room you don't need to prepare it. This would imply that preparing a room would be included in the halacha.